Ring homomorphism from a ring to a field
Since Any ring homomorphism must map group identity to group identity, but on the left hand side is a field and it has two group identities.
So if I consider a ring $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and a field $\mathbb{Z}_3$,then the additive identity of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ must map to group identity of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and it can be zero or one, but why do we always consider zero?

Two group identities? Why?

A field doesn't have group identities, because a field is, strictly speaking, not a group. However, there are two groups associated with every field $F$:

The additive group $(F,+)$ of the field, which contains all field elements and uses field addition as group operation, and
The multiplicative group $(F^\times, \cdot)$ of the field, which contains only non-zero field elements, and uses field multiplication as group operation

The group identity element of the additive group is 0, which is why it is also called the additive identity. For the multiplicative group the identity is is 1, which is also called multiplicative identity.
The same works not only for field but for rings, where for the multiplicative group we must take the set of invertible elements of the ring (in a field, all non-zero elements are automatically invertible by definition).
By definition, a ring homomorphism must map additive identity to additive identity, and multiplicative identity to multiplicative identity. Or, in simpler words, it must map zero to zero and one to one:
$$f(0) = 0$$
$$f(1) = 1$$
So, for a ring homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Z}_6 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_3$, it must be that
$$f([0]_6) = [0]_3$$
and
$$f([1]_6) = [1]_3$$
where $$[x]_6$$ means the equivalence class of $x$ modulo 6.

Thank you so much… i am sorry if my question was trivial. Thanks for your time

There is only one group identidy for the field. 1 is a group identity for the field minus zero and the multiplication law.

Thank you I got it!

My pleasure, and know that your question, though trivial, was worth asking ;) Now your understanding of Fields, Rings and identities is greater.
